# Emacs-lisp hooks for detecting change of active buffer?

Tags: emacs, hook

I am trying to execute when the active buffer has changed by either

1. Changing the buffer in the current window (e.g. `C-x <left>`).
2. Switching to another window (`C-x o`).
3. Switching to another frame.

Are their hooks suitable for detecting this?

### What I figured out so far

Looking through the [Standard Hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html) I found the following options, none of which quite do what I want:

- `buffer-list-update-hook` is called for both (1) and (2). It is however unsuitable, because it is run *before* the buffer is changed, while I want to know what the `current-buffer` *after* the change is.
- `window-configuration-change-hook` can be used to detect a change of the buffer displayed in the current window, and it is run *after* the change, as needed. It is however not run for `M-x other-window`.
- `mouse-leave-buffer-hook` seems viable for detecting mouse-based window switching, but it gets called a bit often (for me four times upon switching windows with the mouse, three times before and once after switching), which requires additional logical to prevent multiple execution.
- `post-command-hook` would be viable but a bit heavy handed, risking significant slow-down of the editor by even minor bugs.
- Since my action would need to use `with-selected-window`, which triggers these hooks, care has to be taken to avoid endless loops where the hook triggers itself.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is recording your current location stuff with the `pre-command-hook` and comparing that data to that which becomes avaialable when running the `post-command-hook` and then put in conditions in your function attached to the latter hook that either exit or continue processing to achieve the desired effect.  I'm surprised the `buffer-list-update-hook` is insufficient with certain conditions attached, including, but not limited to using the `pre-command-hook` to record the relevant data at the beginning of the command, but if you've already experimented and ....

Comment: With the `pre-command-hook`, you would be recording things like:  `(selected-window)`, `this-command`, `(selected-frame)`, `(current-buffer)`.  And, compare that result to the same inquiry on whichever hook you attach your custom function to -- e.g., using the `post-command-hook` or `buffer-list-update-hook` or ....  Keep in mind that `this-command` is short-lived, so you want to record it in a separate variable (probably global).  Your conditions on the latter hook could compare the recorded `this-command` to a list of certain functions that justify taking further action.

Comment: @lawlist When using my own global state-variables, using `buffer-list-update-hook'  does indeed become viable (e.g. by setting a flag, that tells `post-command-hook' that an action is necessary). Since I now also do some checks, when merely swichting lines, I need to use `post-command-hook' anyway. Seems like simpler hooks aren't available.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to include a description of why you are trying to do this.  Even better would be to post the code you're trying to execute.

Comment: Was just looking for the same. I found https://github.com/10sr/switch-buffer-functions-el but haven't had time to play around with it... worth checking out

Comment: Seems that `window-state-change-hook` is what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Emacs27.1 introduce a new variable called `window-buffer-change-functions'

Comment: It looks more like comment then an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) instead, provide [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that don't require clarification from the asker.

Comment: See [`C-h i g (elisp)Window Hooks`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Hooks.html) for more details.

Comment: Is it triggered by `other-window`?

Comment: @T.Verron Just checked : no it is not.

Answer (score 11):

Judging from the comments, the answer to this question is **“No, there is no such hook.”**

Additionally, some of the hooks mentioned in my question, are also triggered by changes, which are not user-visible, such as temporary changes due to `with-current-buffer` and `with-selected-window`.

However, using `post-command-hook` has proven to be a non-issue for performance, since the required state-check is cheap.

### Alternative

Probably obvious, but stated for completeness.

- Store state information in a global variable, in a frame-parameter, in a window-parameter or in a buffer-local variable, whichever is most applicable to the use-case. In my use-case, this necessary unique state is was defined by `current-buffer`, `current-window`, and in one case `line-beginning-position`.*
- In `post-command-hook`, check if the state has changed, possibly skipping 
  even that, if `this-command` is `self-insert-command`.
- If it has, perform the intended action and update the stored state.

---

* `line-number-at-pos` is unsuitable, because it counts lines by iterating over the buffer from `point-min` to `point`, making it generally cheap, but not cheap enough to be executed after every typed character.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like other packages have already solved this problem, but I'm posting here for people who may arrive on this page in their search for answers.

The `treemacs` package uses a minor mode to toggle something called `treemacs-follow-mode` and a timer to call the desired update function after `buffer-list-update-hook`: https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs/blob/master/src/elisp/treemacs-follow-mode.el#L86C15-L86C15

And for #3: Update when changing frames, I used the `after-focus-change-function` like `powerline` does: https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline/blob/master/powerline.el#L575